# is my embedded video replaying itself from cache or from the server?

Tags: http

In this video loop:

```
<video muted id="sensi-video" loop="loop" preload="auto" class="video-playing" 
autoplay="autoplay" poster="<?php echo $poster; ?>">
```

I'm noticing in my Chrome console that the file keeps reloading itself once it's done playing (which is good, I have `loop="loop"`, but I can't determine whether or not the file is loading from the server each time, or whether it's just reloading itself from the user's cache.  Is there a way for me to determine this?

The HTTP status code is 206.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome generally reports a network resource being loaded from cache. In the `Network` tab see the `Size` column. It should report that the resource was loaded `from cache` (see below).

[image]

Comment: So none of these are saying `(from cache)` - is there a way I can force the object to reload from the user's cache?

Comment: @BrianPowell This is more of a server side configuration than a Javascript code hack. On all of your static assets (or long-living assets) you should have headers like `Expires`, `Cache-Control` and `Last-Modified`. You can look up these headers and see how they work. All modern browsers are smart enough to cache such assets.